# search input for fixVersion jira field

Tags: jira

Please tell how to turn on search input for "fix Version" jira ticket's field.

Now I have follow view mode for fix Version field without search input. Only long list:
[image: long list without search]

But I would like following edit mode for fix Version field.

[image: long list with search]

On both screens are different jira versions from different organization.

Question is about input for search by fix Versions. In first screen I can choose version from long scrollable list. I can't input prefix of version for fast choice. Work around is ctrl+F from browser but it is pain.

I would like UX for fix Version field like on second screen. But I don't know how turn on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution - https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-renderers-938847270.html#Configuringrenderers-autocompleterenderer

We should set Autocomplete renderer for fix version field.